# What happens when we call pg_dump while users are still using the system?

Tags: postgresql

We have a web application with PostgreSQL as our database and use celery background tasks for somewhat complex task. At the very beginning of this complex task we take a backup of the database using pg_dump.

I was wondering about the state of this sql dump if the users are still using the system. Could it cause any inconsistencies ?

Also, I would like to know if pg_dump is the best choice for taking backups in this case. Of course as the database grows the backup takes a lot of time which slows the overall process.

Thanks.

Comment: `pg_dump` takes a **consistent** snapshot from the database so it will not cause any inconsistencies.

Comment: So I think it's safe to run it in parallel with the task. Are there any optimizations I can do to make the backups faster?

Comment: Short of buying faster harddisks - no. Note that `pg_dump` creates a "snapshot". Usually that is not considered a backup. Using WAL archiving you can create "real" backups that also allow restoring the data to a specific point in time. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Why do you take the pg_dump before each complex operation?  Is it because you need a backup and this is a convenient time to take one, or is it because you are afraid the operation will go rogue and stomp all over the database?  The easiest way to speed up an operation is not to do that operation in the first place, so it is important to know why it is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering about the state of this sql dump if the users are still using the system

`pg_dump` relies on PostgreSQL's MVCC support to ask PostgreSQL to take a snapshot of the database state at a given point in time.

Changes made by concurrent transactions after the point where `pg_dump` gets its snapshot do not affect `pg_dump`, whether they're committed or not.

There are a few things that aren't necessarily consistent, like sequences, which continue to increase while `pg_dump` is running. But applications have to be prepared for gaps in sequences anyway, so this isn't considered to be a problem.

> Also, I would like to know if pg_dump is the best choice for taking backups in this case

No, you're way better off using WAL archiving and PITR for your purpose. Look into PgBarman and read [the docs on continuous archiving](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html).

You should still take logical dumps for disaster recovery, but it need not be an all-the-time thing.

Comment: Can you please give me some pointers to projects that provide PITR-like functionality for separate database and/or separate schemas ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. You can still do cluster-wide WAL archiving for PITR, then do partial *restores*, though.